# MVC hidden fields values are changing to different values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a contact form where I am passing two values to force the user to answer a simple math question to prove it is not a bot sending the form.

View Model

```
public class ContactFormViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public ContactWho ContactWho { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public ContactFormViewModel()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        Val1 = rnd.Next(1, 9);
        Val2 = rnd.Next(6, 19);
    }
}
```

The viewmodel is passed to the form in the Get call in the controller

```
 private readonly object _cfvm = new ContactFormViewModel();

 public IActionResult Contact()
 {
     return View(_cfvm);
 }
```

The viewmodel DOES get two values from the construction of the model. Proven by looking at the model passed in the controller action and then verified by putting a breakpoint in the view.

View

```
@model ContactFormViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact Us";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutTopLeft.cshtml";
}
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Val1, new { id = "answer_val1" })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Val2, new { id = "answer_val2" })
@{
    var answerPlaceholder = @"What is " + Model.Val1 + " + " +
                        Model.Val2 + "?";
}
```

This produces the text of the answer textbox placeholder which comes in the form of "What is 5 + 12? ( the values come from the view model)

The answerPlaceholder is created correctly BUT the hidden fields have different values then the model.

Example

On running this now and having three breakpoints, one in the controller to see what values are in Val1 and Val2, one in the view on the HiddendFields and one in the answerPlaceholder. Val1 is 8 and Val2 is 11 in the controller, the model in the view and answerPlaceholder is created correctly.

What I don't get, is in the view source the values of the hidden fields are NOT 8 and 11.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Val1 field is required." id="answer_val1" name="Val1" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Val2 field is required." id="answer_val2" name="Val2" type="hidden" value="7" />
```

So i tried using the new MVC 6 method of hidden fields.

```
<input asp-for="Val1" type="hidden" />
<input asp-for="Val2" type="hidden" />
```

But got the same results.

Val1 and Val2 are ONLY needed during the form fill out process and ARE NOT used when the form data is posted back.

This always worked for me like this when using MVC5 but now I am using AspNet Core 2.0 and MVC 6 and wondering if there is something within those frameworks that is causing this. My best guess is somehow ANOTHER version of the viewmodel's model is getting created when populating the values in the hidden fields.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Per Malcor's suggestion, the viewmodel was changed to remove the constructor and the the HttpGet method was changed to add the values in the model there prior to being passed into the view.

```
 public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var cvfm = new ContactFormViewModel
        {
            Val1 = rnd.Next(1, 9),
            Val2 = rnd.Next(6, 19)
        };


        return View(cvfm);
    }
```

All works fine now.

Comment: Answers go in the answer section, no the question! Either suggest an edit to Malcor's answer or add you own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's probably because you're generating new values in the constructor of the class. Remember the model is only defining the structure of your data, the view is constructing it's own version of the class which is generating new values from the Rand. This is probably popping up some unusual behavior. Instead of generating the values on the constructor what happens if you pass in two values through the constructor? I'd imagine you'd get an error because the view doesn't know how to handle the constructor parameters. You're probably best instantiating the class and passing the values for Val1 and Val2 directly.

Comment: @Malcor...I originally thought that was the case but the values of Val1 and Val2 are the same in the cfvm being passed to the view as they are in the this.Context.Model that is in the view while it is being created and the answerPlaceholder is being created with the same values so the model in the view once its first displayed are correct, but the hidden fields dont have those values. And If the model is not passed into the view, it errors on creation

Comment: What happens if you don't use the HTMLHelper and manually put in the html tag with the values? like  `<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Val2 field is required." id="answer_val2" name="Val2" type="hidden" value="@Model.Val1" />`

Comment: Your original comment is correct, if I remove the constructor in the viewmodel, create a new viewmodel in the IActionResult and populate Val1 and Val2 there and pass that model in, it all works correctly. Post that answer and I will accept.

Comment: It is more helpful to future viewers to see the answer in code. I’ll add it as an update in the original post.

Comment: I'll update this answer with code examples when I get to a computer.

Comment: I already added it to the original post, no need. Your answer was accepted.